# Where can I download those bible verses in JSON or XML or SQL formatted file?

Tags: data-request, json, sql, religion, xml

I need to make a site that has Chinese bible verses as well as English bible verses.

Where can I download those in MySQL, XML or JSON format? Can I download them for free? I need NIV version and 和合本 version.

UPDATES:
here are examples of site, data I want to make.
http://www.o-bible.com/cgibin/ob.cgi?chapter=1&book=gen&version=hb5&version=kjv&version=bbe
http://www.o-bible.com/cgibin/ob.cgi?version=hb5&book=mat&chapter=2

Comment: The NIV is relatively new, and might be subject to copyright in the US.  [Bible Study Tools](http://www.biblestudytools.com/niv/) has the NIV, but not as a simple download like lots of sites have for the [King James](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/10).  It also has [footnotes](http://www.biblica.com/bibles/chapter/?verse=John+1&version=niv) in it that might make it more complex to encode.

Comment: Here is a King James Bible in MySQl https://github.com/snowballrandom/kingjamesbible.git

Comment: @Joe is dead on. There are many copies of copyrighted bibles floating around in source repositories for opensource software that can't be used without permission. See here for example https://www.harpercollinschristian.com/permissions/

Answer (score 8):

Disclaimer: I am the author of below github projects.

Two very good (and complete) sources are:

https://github.com/scrollmapper/bible_databases :

This has many database formats including all three formats you are inquiring of.

https://github.com/scrollmapper/bible_databases_deuterocanonical :

This is a newer continuance of the bible databases, but with secondary books (ie, the Deuterocanonical ones). This is just sqlite at present but easy to convert. It is also based in a Django project.

Comment: thanks for this. Do you know how to find the paragraph separator? Are there any? The .JSON file seems to have only verses and chapters?

Answer (score 7):

Below are a couple of sites that have API access to bible text.

http://bibles.org/pages/api - This site has a well-documented API and serve a number of versions. They may have a version that suits your purposes - although NIV is not listed it is mentioned in the API documentation.

http://labs.bible.org/api_web_service - This site has what looks to be a very flexible API that can serve XML, JSON or text.

As for a Chinese language version, the following site has an API in beta but does list Chinese among its many languages:

http://www.4-14.org.uk/xml-bible-web-service-api

Comment: Hi, Thanks.

Do you have some source that allow you download it as a zip file or sql file?

Comment: I perfer to host it in myself than having to call api, go to other's server.

Comment: Then setup a process to call it once. Extract it and load it.

Comment: yea. but i think maybe there are some copyright issue, I will need to answer if some guy ask me for some sort of license or the right to use, publish. I want someone to give me some info.

Comment: and having a file to download is easier. I look for more answers.

Answer (score 4):

Should these help you !

[Bibles in JSON & XML](http://nehemiah.io/bibles-in-json-format/)

[Bibles versions in SQL format](http://nehemiah.io/bible-sql-format/)

Comment: Great Resources !!! God bless you for this brother.

Comment: Those links are dead.

Comment: I was able to grab the KJV version in JSON and I believe a variety of versions in a SQL dump file https://github.com/phillipsk/Open_Verse

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/godlytalias/Bible-Database also have a good database collection

Comment: Don't just dump links; *good* says nothing. Actually, there is no Chinese version there.

Answer (score 1):

This url is [allows for searching of multiple formats of the bible](https://www.ph4.org/b4_poisk.php?text=reina+valera&abbr=0).